# Apache Laravel Installation - Links

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I'm setting up Laravel on my Hostgator shared Web Hosting and I'm have an issue with how links are parsed on my website.

I'm following a simple tutorial for how to create links within Laravel without needing to produce more actual .php files, but the way to access these links I have to do `www.samplewebsite.com/index.php/contact`

How would I setup my .htaccess to that link becomes `www.samplewebsite.com/contact.php` instead?

-- Update --

My directory structure is as follows:

`/`
- This contains my laravel installation as my `php`, `perl5`, `etc`, and my `public_html` folder.

My Laravel installation structure is as follows:

`/app_base/` with the public folder being `/app_base/public/`.

I made a Demo folder in my public_html (www) folder which acts as my test environment so I get to grips with the development before starting with the proper website.

`/public_html/DEMO`

-index.php-

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Laravel - A

 PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels nice to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../../app_base/bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../../app_base/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel');

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

My .htaccess file is contained in my public_html folder. It follows as:

```
RewriteEngine on

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^spotoncreative\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.spotoncreative\.net$
RewriteRule ^default\.html$ "http\:\/\/www\.spotoncreative\.net\/Splash\/" [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^spotoncreative\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.spotoncreative\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.spotoncreative\.net\/Splash\/" [R=301]
```

I hope this helps more.

Comment: Try to use .htaccess and set the directory index http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Comment: And also check this http://laravel.com/docs/4.2#pretty-urls

Comment: These don't do anything for me, just give me the same 500 internal server error. I'll post an update with my dir structure and how I've setup my laravel site.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Laravel `.htaccess` in your `/public` folder.

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The only place I have a .htaccess is in my /public_html/ folder. See updated question for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You need for all queries to your site to go to the /public/index.php file. The index.php file will trigger Laravel to start and go through your routes.  If you have the route '/contact' defined in your route file, then www.samplewebsite.com/contact will route where ever you have it directed. From what I've read, the best practice is to place the app outside of your root folder, and then place an alias in the route that redirects to /public/index.php of your app where it sits on your server.  That way, when you push new code you can push the code first, then change the alias once everything is up and running. If you need to roll back it also makes that much easier.

I'm not too great with tweaking Apache servers and would prefer to use something like Heroku where I can just put a webroot to /public/index.php in the Procfile. If you are just getting started with Laravel and what I said above doesn't make much sense, I'd recommend going the Heroku root, which is free at the development scale.

Here's a great tutorial on deploying to Heroku using a Laravel MySql/PHP stack: https://mattstauffer.co/blog/installing-a-laravel-app-on-heroku